# Calling a form from a string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Application in C# and I need to call a **Form** whose name is saved into a string variable in run-time.

Like;

I already have the form; **Login.cs**

```
string formToCall = "Login"
Show(formToCall)
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/540066/969613

Comment: Yes, but you almost certainly don't want to do it that way.  There are better ways of designing your application.  If you addressed your problem at a larger scope we could help you with that.

Comment: Are you sure that the string will be a valid form name? What about Namespaces?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @Bridge. :) and namespace is something. I can do this using if or switch case. But I wonder if it is possible in this way.

Comment: @Servy I'm preparing a Pocket PC program that is gonna be used in some factories. This is not a big issue but I just wondered.

Comment: @Mtok Like I said, this is the wrong avenue to pursue down.  You shouldn't be implementing any of the answers proposed, but a proper approach can't be given with the information you've provided.

Comment: @Mtok That's too far out in scope.  How are you determining what form you should open (meaning where does the string come from).  Do you have a fixed number of forms, is it a small or large number, is it likely to change much, a bit, never, etc.

Comment: @Servy The form name is coming from the Database. According to the buttons clicked, I specify which form should be opened. Forms are fixed. Fixed number of forms (small number) with fixed names. It is not likely to change much.

Comment: @Mtok In that case I'd create an enumeration, rather than using strings, and use a `switch` in a factor method to create the form given an enumeration value.  The fact that the data is persisted in a database pretty much prevents a purely polymorphic solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [`Activator.CreateInstance(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx):

```
Activator.CreateInstance("Namespace.Forms", "Login");
```

you can also use the `Assembly` class (in `System.Reflection` namespace):

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("Login");
```

Comment: If you do this, how do you get events like the Form Load event to trigger? From my testing, Activator.CreateInstance only executes the constructor but not the Form Load event.

Answer (score 4):

Using reflection:

```
//note: this assumes all your forms are located in the namespace "MyForms" in the current assembly.

string formToCall = "Login"
var type = Type.GetType("MyForms." + formtocall);
var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;

if (form != null)
   form.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

For more dynamic so you can place your form in any folder :

```
public static void OpenForm(string FormName)
{
    var _formName = (from t in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                     where t.Name.Equals(FormName)
                     select t.FullName).Single();
    var _form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_formName));
    if (_form != null) 
    _form.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var form = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(formToCall);
form.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

### (Form)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance()

```
    Form frm = (Form)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("namespace.form");
    frm.Show();
```