# C# call a method using string

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a method that can be called via obj.description

```
public class FromJS
{
    public String description { get; set; }
}

FromJS obj = new FromJS();
obj.description;
```

is it possible to call it like this

```
String val = "description";

obj.val
```

Comment: You're looking for reflection.  However, that is usually a bad idea.

Comment: how to do that on reflection? and why is it a bad idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ProgramFOX but I dont understand that.

Comment: @momokjaaaaa So read about the reflection something on the internet and then come back. You can't really skip studying if you want to use knowledge.

Comment: If you use the `GetPropValue` method of that question, just use this code: `string descr = (string)GetPropValue(obj, "description");`

Comment: @OndrejJanacek let's just say I am a slow learner who had done my homework but still couldnt get it right therefore I jumped into stackoverflow looking for help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is way too broad, and the person asking could have done the research suggested to him in the comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function from a string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the question is coming from a user having experience in scripting languages (that have late-binding for methods, properties by default). Those languages usually support easy syntax for "evaluating" a string as a piece of program.

C# is a stongly typed language and it supports late-binding as an exception, so there is no straight-forward solution as an eval() in php, perl, python or ruby. When working with C#, please either try to find a solution where you do not need such tricks, or use reflection as some comments suggested.

A beginner's intro for reflection in .NET: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/