# How to call an appropriate method by string value from collection?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, switch-statement, console-application

I have a collection of strings. For example,

```
string[] coll={"1", "2", "3" ..."100"..."150"...}
```

and I have respective methods for the string collection such as

```
void Method1, void Method2, void Method100
```

I select appropriate method like that:

```
string selector=string.Empty;
switch(selector)
 { case "1": 
            MethodOne();
            break;
    ........
    case "150":
            Method150();
            break;
  }
```

The above code is really bored and I will have more string elements in the string collection {"150" ... "250"...}.
     How to make like that:

```
 string sel=col[55];
 if(sel!=null)
        // call here the respective         method(method55)
```

I do not want to use switch operator cause it gives rise to surplus of code.

Comment: `Dictionary<string,Action>`

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Eser write your answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @StepUp You have similar answer. Better accept it.

Comment: @Eser I've given points to the answers. Your answer were earlier and the first. It is fair.

Comment: @StepUp OK. I posted one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a dictionary with your keys and actions like

```
Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { "1", MethodOne },
    { "2", ()=>Console.WriteLine("test") },
    ............
};
```

and invoke it as

```
actions["1"]();
```

PS: Presuming method `void MethodOne(){ }` is declared somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you know how to call "void MethodOne(int x)"? Method with parameter

Comment: @StepUp `()=>MethodOne(i)` ? Maybe declaring `Dictionary<string, Action<int>>` and then `actions["1"](i)`. Depends on your case...

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Use a delegate mapping. This is the faster solution.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Action> mapping =
    new Dictionary<string, Action>
    {
        { "1", MethodOne },
        // ...
        { "150", Method150 }
    };

public void Invoker(string selector)
{
    Action method;
    if (mapping.TryGetValue(selector, out method)
    {
        method.Invoke();
        return;
    }

    // TODO: method not found
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Use reflection. This is slower and is appropriate only if your methods have strict naming (eg. 1=MethodOne 150=Method150 will not work).

```
public void Invoker(string selector)
{
    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Method" + selector);
    if (method != null)
    {
        method.Invoke(this, null);
        return;
    }

    // TODO: method not found
}
```

Comment: You can also combine the two solutions: have a dictionary of delegates and fill it using reflection. That gives you the efficiency of solution 1, while not repeating code like solution 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic invocation

```
 var methodName = "Method" + selector;
 var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
 if (method == null)
 {
    // show error
 }
 else
    method.Invoke(this, null);
```