# Calling method with generic type using class name as string

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, eval

Having this class :

```
class ClassA{
}
```

and a method with this signature:

```
void MyMethod<T>();
```

All we use it on this way:

```
MyMethod<ClassA>();
```

But... exist some chance of call `MyMethod` having the class name as string?. I.e.:

```
var className = "ClassA";

MagicMethod($"MyMethod<{className}>();");
```

Im talking about some equivalent of `Eval` in JavaScript. Reflection?, Any idea?

I googled some libraries like [DynamicExpresso](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/) but nothing with support for generic types.

About possible duplicates:

- [Calling a function from a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp) not solve my problem, my question is specific to call methods **with generics types**.

Comment: Or ```Type t = Type.GetType(string_name_of_type);```, more docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think is not same case in [Calling a function from a string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp) because that sample not use Generics Types.

Comment: @Alexander, I don't think this is duplicate...

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk, we need to use reflection and as I understand problem is to call generic method. And it is what "Use Reflection to call..." question about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing you have the following method:

```
public class Foo
{
     public void MyMethod<T>();
}
```

You may get the [MethodInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("MyMethod");
```

Now, let's say you have this class:

```
public class exampleB
{
}
```

You can invoke the generic method using the generic parameter type's name:

```
string genericTypeName = "exampleB";
Type genericType = Type.GetType(genericTypeName);
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("MyMethod").MakeGenericMethod(genericType);

// You will need an instance of Foo to invoke it (the method isn't static)
methodInfo.Invoke(fooInstance, null);
```

Of course, this will require the run-time to search for type `B`, so you should be careful and specify the correct namespace too.