# Call a void from a string

Tags: c#, string, call, void

My application is defining the method name to the string at runtime. And I want to call that method from string.

Example

```
private void ButtonClick(){
    string goVoid;
    goVoid = "testVoid";
    goVoid(); // Calling testVoid
}

testVoid(){
    //code
}
```

Comment: My gut tells me you're trying to do something the Cthulhu, err... PHP way here... You can do this by using reflection if you **must**, but maybe you should explain the real reason you need to do something like that. Please read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Have a look at [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).. but I'd first think about other ways to model your application.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, Should i remove my answer and post it as duplicate ?

Comment: @OrelEraki well, Enigmativity dupehammered the question (I was on the fence of doing this myself anyway). I'd say leave it, you give proper attribution for the code so its presence is not harmful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a method by specifying the string name alone in a normal straightforward way, you can only do it by using reflection.
Other means will not be dynamic and probably will be a **switch** flow control that will call the method you need based on a match.

For the following you will need `System.Reflection`

```
string methodName = "testVoid";
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(methodName);
theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/540075/303254

Comment: The OP may need to use the binding flags `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` if `testVoid` is `private`. His code is not very clear on this.

Comment: You're right, didn't wanted to over complicated things, i'm still wondering if to remove my answer and mark it as duplicate.