# Unity: Null while making new class instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null

I got stuck in pretty dumb situation: I'm making new instance of the generic class but it returns "weird" null.

```
    Rule rule2 = new Rule(); // initiate the class
    Debug.Log(rule2); //1st debug
    rule2.RuleSetup(r: "CaughtEnough", li: 0); //setting up the parameters
    Debug.Log(rule2.rule); //2nd debug
```

1st debug gives me

```
    null
    UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

at the same time setting up the parameters works, and 2nd debug gives me

```
   CaughtEnough
   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

which is what supposed to be in the proper class instance.

One (only so far) issue that it is bringing to me is that if whitin this Rule class instance I call

```
   Invoke(rule, 0f);
```

it gives me the NullReferenceException error. But at the same time the actual function

```
   CaughtEnough();
```

works just fine and as expected.

Any ideas what could be the source of the problem and how to overcome it?

UPD also posting setup part of Rule class, as asked, though it is straightforward

```
public class Rule : MonoBehaviour {

public string rule;

public int leftInt;
public Dictionary<string, int> leftDict;
public float countdown;

public int outcome;

public CatchManager catchMan;
public Net net;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    RuleSetup();   
}

public void RuleSetup(string r = "NoRule", int li = 0, Dictionary<string, int> ld = null,  float cd = float.PositiveInfinity) {
    rule = r;
    leftInt = li;
    leftDict = ld;
    countdown = cd;
}
.....
```

Comment: Just check if rule2 is null by doing if(rule2==null){Debug.Log("null")}else{Debug.Log("Not null")}. Also post your Rule class so that we can see what RuleSetup is.

Comment: Thanks, I checked as you suggested, and rule2 is indeed null.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> ```
> public class Rule : MonoBehaviour{}
> Rule rule2 = new Rule();
> ```

You **can't** use `new` keyword to create new instance if you are inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`.

*You should get exception that says*:

> You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. 
>   This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using
>   AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from
>   ScriptableObject or no base class at all

Your code would have worked if you had `public class Rule {}` but you have `public class Rule : MonoBehaviour {}`.

**Creating new instance of class that derives from `MonoBehaviour`:**

*Example class:*

```
public class Rule : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rule(int i)
    {

    }
}
```

If you inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, you should either use `GameObject.AddComponent` or `Instantiate` to create new instance of it.

```
Rule rule2 = null;
void Start()
{
  rule2 = gameObject.AddComponent<Rule>();
}
```

*OR*

```
public Rule rulePrefab;
Rule rule2;
void Start()
{
    rule2 = Instantiate(rulePrefab) as Rule;
}
```

If the `Rule` script already exist and is attached to the GameObject, you don't need to create/add/instantiate new instance of that script. Just use `GetComponent` function to get the script instance from the GameObject it is attached to.

```
Rule rule2;
void Start()
{
    rule2 = GameObject.Find("NameObjectScriptIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Rule>();
}
```

You will notice that you **cannot** use the parameter in the constructor when you derive your script from `MonoBehaviour`.

---

---

**Creating new instance of class that does NOT derives from `MonoBehaviour`:**

*Example class: (Note that it does not derive from "`MonoBehaviour`"*

```
public class Rule
{
    public Rule(int i)
    {

    }
}
```

If you **don't** inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, you should use the `new` keyword to create new instance of it. Now, you **can** use the parameter in the constructor if you want.

```
Rule rule2 = null;

void Start()
{
    rule2 = new Rule(3);
}
```

**EDIT**:

<sup>In the latest version of Unity, creating new instance of a script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour` with the `new` keyword may not give you error and may not be `null` too *but all the callback functions will not execute*. These includes the  `Awake`, `Start`,  `Update` functions and others. So, you still have to do it properly as mentioned at the top of this answer.</sup>

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you. That looks for me as a really weird convention.

Comment: @Alex New Unity users experience that and that includes me. Oh and make sure to do the-same thing when creating instance of `CatchManager` and `Net` that are inside the `Rule` script

Comment: Thank again, everything else is actually solid objects with prefabs n' staff. Don't know why I thought I could go with just a class in the case of Rule :)

Answer (score 2):

Just a a follow up, how I ended up doing it and why:

1. I no longer inherit the `Rule` class from `MonoBehaviour` to avoid tracking cretion and deletion of the gameObjects, which appeared to be the pain.
2. As `Invoke` method does not exist in generic classes, I replaced it with reflection, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp)