# An object reference is required for the non-static field in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basicaly I want to get float variable from script **SimpleLUT** to **WriteJson**. All done in Unity 5.6 and Visual Studio 2015. Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

*SimpleLUT.cs*

```
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace DigitalRuby.SimpleLUT
    {
        [ExecuteInEditMode]
        public class SimpleLUT : MonoBehaviour
        {

            [Range(0, 360)]
            [Tooltip("Hue")]
            public float Hue = 0.0f;

    //rest of the code
```

*WriteJson.cs*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using LitJson;
using DigitalRuby.SimpleLUT;

public class WriteJson : MonoBehaviour {

    public SimpleLUT script;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Camera");
        SimpleLUT simpleLUT = camera.GetComponent<SimpleLUT>();

    }

public class ColorCorrectionSettings
    {
        public float JsonHue;
        public float JsonAmount;
        public float JsonSaturation;
        public float JsonBrightness;
        public float JsonContrast;

        public ColorCorrectionSettings(float JsonHue, float JsonAmount, float JsonSaturation, float JsonBrightness, float JsonContrast)
        {
            SimpleLUT.Hue = JsonHue; //<- here is the error
        }
    }

}
```

The SimpleLUT.Hue does not work. As it is non static, other static variables are accessable.

Comment: Why not just pass a reference of `SimpleLUT` into the constructor for `ColorCorrectionSettings`?

Comment: What makes you think it should work? `ColorCorrectionSettings` does not have a property called `SimpleLUT` and the `Hue` property is not static

Comment: I am newbie here. Would you care to explain or link me to some decent help?

Comment: I would recommend picking up a book on the basics/fundamentals of  c#.  If you just want guidance on your specific problem, look into the difference between static members and instance members.

Comment: Your error here is a typo.  Change `SimpleLUT.Hue` to `simpleLUT.Hue` (changes the reference from the static *Class* reference to the *instance* reference)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is your `SimpleLUT` script:

```
public class SimpleLUT : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 360)]
    [Tooltip("Hue")]
    public float Hue = 0.0f;
}
```

You can't access the `Hue` variable directly with `SimpleLUT.Hue = JsonHue;` because the Hue  variable is not a `static` variable.

You have two optiopns:

**1**.Make the `Hue` variable static.

So, `public float Hue = 0.0f;` should be `public static float Hue = 0.0f;`.

I am sure you don't want this because it won't show up in the Editor when you make it static.

**2**.Create instance of SimpleLUT or get the instance.

Find the GameOjbect the SimpleLUT is attached to:

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("GameOjbectSimpleLUTScriptIsAttachedTo");
```

Get the `SimpleLUT` script instance that is attached to that GameObject:

```
SimpleLUT simpleLUTInstance = obj.GetComponent<SimpleLUT>();
```

Now, you can access the `Hue` variable:

```
simpleLUTInstance.Hue = JsonHue;
```

Finally, this what it should look like:

```
public ColorCorrectionSettings(float JsonHue, float JsonAmount, float JsonSaturation, float JsonBrightness, float JsonContrast)
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("GameOjbectSimpleLUTScriptIsAttachedTo");
    SimpleLUT simpleLUTInstance = obj.GetComponent<SimpleLUT>();
    simpleLUTInstance .Hue = JsonHue; //<- No more error
}
```

Don't forget to replace *"GameOjbectSimpleLUTScriptIsAttachedTo"* with the name of GameObject the `SimpleLUT` script is attached to.

Comment: Aha! So the instance should be right before the linking. Thank you for the final look.

Comment: If `SimpleLUT` is attached to a GameObject then the instance exist on that GameObject. If it is not attached to any GameObject, you can create new instance with `AddComponent` since `SimpleLUT` inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398538/unity-null-while-making-new-class-instance/37399263#37399263) for more information.