# Unity3D /C# - What's the difference between instantiating a prefab as a GameObject vs a component class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say I had a prefab called `Bullet` with a script attached called `BulletControl.cs`.

I could instantiate it as: `GameObject bulletInstance = Instantiate(Bullet, transform);`
Or I could do: `BulletControl bulletInstance = Instantiate(Bullet, transform);`

I originally thought that instantiating as a `GameObject` was just a more general type that gave you access to other parameters like transform. Instantiating, to my understanding, isn't like using the `new` keyword, so I don't think that when I declare bulletInstance's type I'm creating an instance of the class BulletControl. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) function takes [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) as argument.

In Unity, every `GameObject` and components/scripts inherits from [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) directly or indirectly.

Let's say that the name of your script is called `YourScript`:

`YourScript` inherits from `MonoBehaviour`

```
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

then `MonoBehaviour`  inherits from `Behaviour`

```
public class MonoBehaviour : Behaviour
{

}
```

and `Behaviour` inherits from `Component`.

```
public class Behaviour : Component
{

}
```

Finally, `Component`  inherits from `Object`.

```
public class Component : Object
{

}
```

---

For `GameObject`, it inherits from `Object` directly.

```
public sealed class GameObject : Object
{

}
```

Because of this, any class that inherits from `Object` should be able to be instantiated with the [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) function.

> Instantiating, to my understanding, isn't like using the new keyword

If your script does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` then you can use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of it like a normal C# program. If it inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, you have to use the [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) or the [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398538/unity-null-while-making-new-class-instance/37399263#37399263) post for more information.

Comment: Also, Instantiate is faster than creation by code when it comes to add many components. At least, one quick benchmark we did showed so. Could be that since Unity knows ahead what the prefab requires, it may optimize the process. To be confirmed.

Comment: *"Instantiate is faster than creation by code"* Can you explain what you mean by creation by code?

Comment: When you have GameObject obj = new GameObject("name", typeof(SomeType), typeof(SomeOtherType)); and then you have a prefab with already attached types and you use Instantiate(prefab), we noticed it goes faster by a large scale. It was in our case, but I can't rule it for all cases so this is why I say to be confirmed.

Comment: Oh I see. I haven't really done that test but that might be true. It seems like the first method you mentioned is using reflection a-lot. Plus, it takes string as a parameter for the name of the GameObject..That string could cause memory allocation just like `GameObject.tag`. Maybe those are the reasons.