# Using static variable in different class in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have the following code

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    private static int score;
    public int sc;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
        if (col.tag == "Ball") {
            score++;
            sc = score;
        }
    }
```

and this is the class I'm using to get the score from the class above

```
public class ScoreText : MonoBehaviour {

    Score s = new Score();
    int sc;

    void Update () {
        sc = s.sc;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, my sc variable in the class ScoreText is always 0. How can I fix that?

Comment: Both answers are wrong. Do not use the `new` keyword to create instance  of script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37399263/3785314) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of a static variable with class.property

```
public class ScoreText : MonoBehaviour {

    int sc =0 ;

    void Update () {
        sc = Score.score;
    }
}
```

And change private static int score; for public static int score;

Answer (score 0):

Change `private static int score;` to `public static int score;` and call it like this: `Score.score = 5;`

If you want to use it as property, you can do the following:

```
private static int _score;

public int score {
   get{return _score;} 
   set{_score = value;}
}
```