# You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am uploading data to database using WWW.
I have two data classes for data object.

```
[Serializable]
public class pushdatawrapper{
    public string email;
    public pushdata[] shotsArray=new pushdata[1];
}
[Serializable]
public class pushdata{
    public string timehappened;
    public string clubtype;     
    public pushdata(string timestamp_,string clubtype_)
    {
        timehappened = timestamp_;
        clubtype = clubtype_;           
    }
}
```

Loading Json array of data object to database, I tried two approaches.
The first one was ok, but the second one is always failed at calling `StartCoroutine` function.

`First approach`

```
public class BLEBridge : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
       pushdata_ pdata = new pushdata_("123123123123.0","15","123.0","123.0", "123.0", "123.0","123.0", "123.0","123.0","123.0","123.0","123.0", "First");
        pushdatawrapper_ pw = new pushdatawrapper_ ();
        pw.email = "test@gmail.com";
        pw.shotsArray[0] = pdata;
        StartCoroutine (PushData_ (pw));
    }

    private IEnumerator PushData_(pushdatawrapper_ pdata){
        WWW www;
        Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
        postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        string dataToJason = JsonUtility.ToJson(pdata);
        Debug.Log ("dataToJason " + dataToJason);
        // convert json string to byte
        var formData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToJason);
        www = new WWW("http://rmotion.rapsodo.com/api/push/new", formData, postHeader);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
        return www;

    }
    IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW data)
    {
        yield return data; // Wait until the download is done
        if (data.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("There was an error sending request: " + data.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Request: " + data.text);
        }
    }

}
```

This first method is always ok.
But in actual implementation, I need to upload data from a static function. Those `private IEnumerator PushData_(pushdatawrapper_ pdata) and IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW data)` can't be static.

So what I did was
I made a separate class as

```
public class UploadData: MonoBehaviour{
    public void uploadindividualshot(pushdatawrapper pw){       
        StartCoroutine (PushData (pw));


    }

    private IEnumerator PushData(pushdatawrapper pdata){
        WWW www;
        Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
        postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        string dataToJason = JsonUtility.ToJson(pdata);
        Debug.Log ("dataToJason " + dataToJason);
        // convert json string to byte
        var formData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToJason);
        Debug.Log ("before www ");
        www = new WWW("http://rmotion.rapsodo.com/api/push/new", formData, postHeader);
        Debug.Log ("after new ");
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
        Debug.Log ("after WaitForRequest ");
        return www;

    }
    IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW data)
    {
        Debug.Log ("start pushing ");
        yield return data; // Wait until the download is done
        if (data.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("There was an error sending request: " + data.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Request: " + data.text);
        }
    }

}
```

Then call the instance of the class from static method as

```
public class BLEBridge : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){}

    public unsafe static void GetGolfREsult()
    {
       pushdata pdata = new pushdata("123123123123.0","15","123.0","123.0", "123.0", "123.0","123.0", "123.0","123.0","123.0","123.0","123.0", "First");
       pushdatawrapper pw = new pushdatawrapper();
       pw.email = Login.loginName;
       pw.shotsArray[0] = pdata;
       UploadData up = new UploadData ();
        up.uploadindividualshot (pw);
    }
}
```

I always have error as

```
after new 
UploadData:PushData(pushdatawrapper)
BLEBridge:GetGolfREsult()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Il2CppExceptionWrapper
2018-04-29 17:25:25.565292+0800 RMotion[270:7241] You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
```

The program has error at `StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));`

What is wrong with second approach?

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: 2017.2.0f3 personal

Comment: While the duplicate explains your error, there very serious issues with your code: **1**. When you called `WaitForRequest`, you should yield it to actually wait until the `WaitForRequest` function returns. That should be changed to `yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));`. **2**. The `UploadData` class derives from `MonoBehaviour`. You can't use the `new` keyword to create new instances of it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398538/unity-null-while-making-new-class-instance/) post for how to create instance of a class that derives from`MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks. Initially I was trying to push every data I receive at static method to server. Calling `MonoBehaviour` class from a static method has some issue. I followed the link you mentioned, but still have issues. So I changed my approach as stored data into a sqlite table first and push to server when the app switches to background mode. So I don't need to deal with static method. But your comment is useful for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In unity calling this line of code automatically start http request

```
WWW www = new WWW("url");
```

yield is just the convenience way to tell the coroutine to wait for the process to finish. Don't separate your calls in 2 IEnumerator.

```
private IEnumerator PushData_(pushdatawrapper_ pdata){
    WWW www;
    Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
    postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    string dataToJason = JsonUtility.ToJson(pdata);
    Debug.Log ("dataToJason " + dataToJason);
    // convert json string to byte
    var formData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToJason);
    www = new WWW("http://rmotion.rapsodo.com/api/push/new", formData, postHeader)
    Debug.Log ("start pushing ");
    yield return www; // Wait until the download is done
    if (www.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("There was an error sending request: " + www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Request: " + www.text);
    }

}
```

And I don't see any use of pointer in your static method so why did you use the unsafe keyword?

Comment: where should i put unsafe?

Comment: In your case unsafe keyword is useless to my opinion

Comment: In your case unsafe keyword is useless to my opinion

Comment: This is totally unrelated to what's described in the question