# Determine a object's type based on a string and create a new instance?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to determine a object's type based on a string, then create a new instance of that object?

I am currently doing something like this:

```
switch (type_str){
  case "Square":
    Square S = new Square();
    S.DoSomethingSquarey();
    DoSomething(S);
    break;
  case "Circle":
    Circle C = new Circle();
    C.DoSomethingCircley();
    DoSomething(C);
    break;
  case "Triangle":
    Triangle T = new Triangle();
    T.DoSomethingTriangley();
    DoSomething(T);
    break;
}
```

All types will inherit from base class "Shape":

```
public static void DoSomething(Shape S){
   //Doing Stuff...
}
```

This will quickly get out of hand to maintain as I will need to continually add shapes to the case statement. If possible, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Type ShapeType = Type.GetType("Square");
ShapeType X = new ShapeType();
DoSomething(X);
```

This will cause issues at compile time. Is there another way to simplify this case statement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)?

Comment: There's also Reflection. This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why is comparing it as a string a requirement?  I don't recommend using [magic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) in code generally. Everything you're trying to do becomes multiple times easier if you use the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan current assembly (or whatever assembly that contains your shapes) for types that inherited from `Shape`, and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the instance. It's better if you cache the name and type in a dictionary, so you can quickly lookup the type that you want.

```
var type_str = "Circle";

// TypeChache should be static field
if (TypeChache == null)
{
    var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    TypeChache = assem.GetTypes()
                 .Where(x => typeof(Shape).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                 .ToDictionary(x=>x.Name, x=>x);
}

var type = TypeChache[type_str];    
var inst = (Shape) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
DoSomething(inst);
```