# Unity 5. Raycast compare tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a raycast system to detect items in the world, and if the raycast detects an apple and I press "E" my character should pick up that specific apple. Same goes with any other objects that would be pickable.

I can't figure out a way of doing this neatly besides hard coding every single item with an "IF" statement to check if that specific item was targeted.

I have my thought on Comparing Tags but I don't see how I wouldn't have to hard code everything nontheless.

```
void Fire()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, rayRange))
    {
        // If (Raycast hit enemy) Damage Enemy Accordingly based on weapon damage. 
        // If (Raycast hit Apple) Pick up apple.
        // If (Raycast hit Drink) Pick up drink. 

        Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject); // Debug Only
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name); // Debug Only
    }

    nextFire = Time.time + fireRate; // Don't mind this.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer works if you want to call a function within the hit.transform class.

I thought if you wanted to call a function from within the current Class that the following way is better.

If you wanted to call a function from the fire() function you could always do what is explained in:

[Calling a function from a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp)

just name your functions such as

```
public void HandleApple();
public void HandleEnemy();
```

get the function to call with the name using the "hit" tag

There are a few ways to call a function by name described in the above link, but I think by using the "hit.transform.tag" all you would have to do is name your function related to it's tag

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, rayRange))
string functionName = "Handle" + hit.transform.tag; // tag is "Apple"
```

Then invoke the function by calling the function by "functionName" ("HandleApple")

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the function: GameObject.SendMessage

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, rayRange))
{
    hit.collider.SendMessage("CheckHit");

   // Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject); // Debug Only
   // Debug.Log(hit.transform.name); // Debug Only
}
```

Then in your script for "enemy","Apple" or "Drink" put a function called "CheckHit"

ie

```
public class AppleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void CheckHit();
}
```

If you want to add variables to "CheckHit()" then call

```
hit.collider.SendMessage("CheckHit", 1.0f);

public class AppleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void CheckHit(float something);
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html