# Replace Method name at run time dynamically every time i call in for loop C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to call "**Payment010**" method with different every time i call, example at the iteration it suppose to be called as **Payment010** and at the second iteration i wanted to call as **Payment011**,  Is that possible? 
Much appreciated for help in advance!

```
public class PaymentChargeCreditCard
{
    public async Task Payment010()
    {

        await this.MakePayment(
                orderNo,
                shipDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# reflection can call a function from string.

This might be what you want.

[Calling a function from a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp)