# Is there a way to call a function from a string?

Tags: c#

I want to take a string like `"driverLib.GetTotalRecordCount(\"name_of_table\")"` and run it like a function call.

I followed the instructions from this post:

[Calling a function from a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp)

but I get an error saying the function doesn't exist in MySQLLib.

**Code**:

```
MySQLLib driverLib = new MySQLLib();

string funcName = "driverLib.GetTotalRecordCount";
string userParam = "\"name_of_table\"";

// Code from the link 
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(funcName);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParam);
```

Comment: Searching for „.net expression evaluator“ or something like that on google.

Comment: You're trying to invoke the method on `MySQLLib`. Are you sure that method is available in `MySQLLib`?

Comment: This line `Console.WriteLine(funcCall) // driverLib.GetTable1Data("name_of_table", ref lists)` cannot print what you're showing in the comments either.

Comment: You are referring to a class "driverlib" defined as a property in MySQLLib ? Why do you not use typeof(MySLLib.drivelib) ? why is the "driverlib." prefix needed in the first parameter.. ?

Comment: You need to use the method name, you already have an instance of the type information, so calling a method doesn't require you to qualify the method with the type name, have you tried with just the method name? See the examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember (look at `ToString`). As @codingyoshi says, there's a reference to `driverLib` but what is that? It's not referenced anywhere in your code and shouldn't be.

Comment: @Charleh I have added the class declaration of MySQLLib in my code. driverLib is the name of the object.

Comment: You don't need the name of the object, you created a new instance of the object when you used `Activator.CreateInstance` and stored the created object reference in the `obj` variable. If you want to call the method on `driverLib` you need to pass it in `InvokeMember` in the place of `obj`. `InvokeMember` does not know anything about the context so it doesn't know what `driverLib` is. You have followed a tutorial without understanding it and that's your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go through reflection tutorial? Check this blog:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3027240/how-to-work-with-reflection-in-c.html

What you could do is print all method's name of your MySQLLib and debug it:

```
Type type = typeof(MySQLLib);

MethodInfo[] methodInfo = type.GetMethods();

foreach(var method in methodInfo)
{
    Console.Writeline(method.Name);
}
```